# How to slice long string and output a portion of text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am capturing the user`s session data into a variable and come out as the following:

```
"192605238.|1=Identifiant=FSAPPS\BBF4U5C=1^2=Caisse=GTD95600=1^3=Editeur=False=1^5=Pvp=PVPTSP=1"
```

I am trying to figure out how to capture the data after `FSAPPS\` and before the `=` so in this case I only want to output `BBF4U5C`. This would be the login name of the user and may vary in lenght.

Looking for any help at this point.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var s = "192605238.|1=Identifiant=FSAPPS\BBF4U5C=1^2=Caisse=GTD95600=1^3=Editeur=False=1^5=Pvp=PVPTSP=1"

var res = s.split("FSAPPS")[1].split("=")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hackish way based on finding the start and end indexes in the string. I'm not sure what parts are reliable and what parts aren't but this will work for your specific use case.

```
var str = "192605238.|1=Identifiant=FSAPPS\BBF4U5C=1^2=Caisse=GTD95600=1^3=Editeur=False=1^5=Pvp=PVPTSP=1";

var start = str.indexOf("FSAPPS") + 6;

var end = str.indexOf("=1^2");

alert(str.substring(start, end));//alerts BBF4U5C
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ssyub7a/

Answer (score 0):

Find index of identifier (index of first letter), 
find index od "=" (start looking after identifier)
with this information + known length of identifier you can easily extract sub string containing your login, (bonus points for not destroying your original string)

```
var txt = 
"192605238.|1=Identifiant=FSAPPS\BBF4U5C=1^2=Caisse=GTD95600=1^3=Editeur=False=1^5=Pvp=PVPTSP=1";
var start = txt.indexOf("FSAPPS");
var end = txt.indexOf("=", start);
var login = txt.substring(start + 6, end);
```

Comment: Please add details to explain what you are proposing in your solution so that both the OP and future readers can benefit

Comment: @WandMaker explanation added.